# Unable to access batch() in firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

According to following documentation batching should be available for firestore

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

I have a function with following content

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import createCharacter from './tasks/createCharacter'

const { firestore } = functions

const batch = firestore().batch()
```

However `firestore()` throws an invalid error (using typescript)

> [ts] Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.
>   Type 'typeof
>   import("/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/firestore")'
>   has no compatible call signatures.

Comment: It looks like you need to bring in [firestore from the admin module](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access Firestore like that through the Functions SDK.  What you can do is install the Firestore admin SDK:

```
npm install firebase-admin
```

Then import it and work with the [Firestore APIs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/):

```
import * as admin from firebase-admin
admin.initializeApp()

const firestore = admin.firestore()
// now firestore is a Firestore object
```

`firestore` above is a [Firestore](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/Firestore) object.